# Contour Plot - L-Shaped

Tags: plotting, functions, color

I am trying to plot a contour with an L-shaped form. I started by illustrating the contour function (horizontal, orange) and adding a line (vertical, black).

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Bconstr[x_, y_, px_, py_, R_] = px*x + py*y - R;
f1[px_, py_, R_] := y /. Solve[Bconstr[x, y, px, py, R] == 0, y]
U8[x_, y_, a_, b_] := Min[a*x, b*y];
xstarvalue8[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] := R/(px + a/b*py)
ystarvalue8[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] := R/(b/a*px + py)
opt8[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] := Evaluate[{xstarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b], ystarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b]}]
f8[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] = Quiet[y /. Solve[U8[## & @@ opt8[px, py, R, a, b], a, b] == U8[x, y, a, b], y][[1]]];
f8vertline[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] := Line[{{xstarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b],ystarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b]}, {xstarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b], 1000}}]
hstarline8[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] := Line[{{0, ystarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b]}, {xstarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b], ystarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b]}}]
vstarline8[px_, py_, R_, a_, b_] := Line[{{xstarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b], 0}, {xstarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b], ystarvalue8[px, py, R, a, b]}}]

Manipulate[Plot[{f1[px, py, R], f8[px, py, R, a, b]}, {x, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 1000}, 
Epilog -> {f8vertline[px, py, R, a, b], Red, Dashed, hstarline8[px, py, R, a, b], vstarline8[px, py, R, a, b], 
PointSize@Large, Point@opt8[px, py, R, a, b], Text["Optimal Bundle", opt8[px, py, R, a, b], {-1.1, -2}]}, 
AxesLabel -> {"Good x", "Good y"}, PlotLabel -> "U(x,y)=min{ax,by}", LabelStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> {400, 250}], 
{{px, 5}, 0.01, 30, .5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{py, 10}, .01, 30, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{R, 2500}, 0, 5000, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 1}, 0, 25, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{b, 1}, 0, 25, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
Button["Reset", {px = 5, py = 10, R = 2500, a = 1, b = 1}], ContentSize -> {500, 300}]
```

**How can I**

1.) Replicate the style of the horizontal for the vertical to make it look like one graph;

**or**

2.) Potentially, use a better strategy to illustrate the contour?

**Thank you!**

[image]

Comment: Please post the code about `f1[px, py, R]`.

Comment: Updated - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `ColorData[97, 2]` and  `AbsoluteThickness[1.6]` inside `Epilog` before `f8vertline`.

So the beginning of `Epilog` would look like this:

```
Epilog -> {ColorData[97, 2], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], 
  f8vertline[px, py, R, a, b], (*continue with the rest of your code*)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Properly styled `HalfLine` objects would work best in this context. For instance, `HalfLine[{x, y}, {1, 0}]` would produce a horizontal line segment starting at the point $(x,y)$ and continuing to positive infinity. Similarly, `HalfLine[{x, y}, {0, 1}]` will produce a vertical line segment starting at $(x,y)$ and going upwards. See the last entry in the *Applications* section of the [documentation of `HalfLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HalfLine.html) (i.e. "Add droplines to plots").

```
With[{pt = {1, 2}},
 Graphics[
  {
    {Red, 
     PointSize[0.02], Point[pt],
     Inset[Style["Optimal Bundle", 14], pt, Scaled[{-0.1, -0.3}]],
    },
    {Orange,
     HalfLine[pt, {1, 0}], HalfLine[pt, {0, 1}]
    }
  },
  Axes -> True
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to conflict with Manipulate[Plot[...],Graphics[...]]. Where would you place $Graphics[{Orange, HalfLine[opt8[px, py, R, a, b], {1000, 0}], 
  HalfLine[opt8[px, py, R, a, b], {0, 1000}]}]$ in the above Manipulate section?